# Cannot save some fields like 'Telephone', 'Email', 'Tax',.. of Sales Employee using DI API

Tags: c#, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I want to add (or update) sale employee (database table: OSLP) using DI API. The object to use is SalesPerson, but in its public properties I dont see 'Telephone', 'Mobile', 'Fax',... I just added successfully a record without these properties, it means that I used the correct service (SalesPerson). So how I can add a record with fields like: Telephone, Mobile, ... ? Thanks in advance.

Please check my images for more info:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the EmployeesInfo Object:

```
SAPbobsCOM.EmployeesInfo EmployeeInfo = objCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oEmployeesInfo);
EmployeeInfo.GetByKey("BOB");
EmployeeInfo.Remarks = "Always Late!";
```

Comment: I dont think it work, EmployeesInfo Object process data in table OHEM, I want  to add record to table OSLP.

Comment: My Apologies, it seems as though the properties you mentioned are not exposed to the DI. Could it be performed in code through the UI ?

Comment: "Could it be performed in code through the UI ?", sorry, I dont get it.

Comment: You could try to open the form on screen within the sap application, find the final row and add the data directly to the grid, then force a click event on the button.

Comment: We use DI API on our own application, we have 2 options: save data using DI service or save data using our service (execute sql command). I think DI API doesn't have object for this task.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. And sry for my bad English =))

Comment: no problem, your english is perfect :)  i think there is no way to set this property, could you create  a user field, call it 'mobile2' and set that with the DI?

Answer (score 0):

In the OP's graphic, you see the *EmployeeID*, which is a foreign key to the EmployeesInfo object.

If you have loaded a salesperson record into memory as a SalesPersons object named "oslp", this is how you'd update the mobile phone:

```
var ohem = company.GetBusinessObject( BoObjectTypes.oEmployeesInfo ) as EmployeesInfo;
if ( ohem.GetByKey( oslp.EmployeeId ) ) {
  ohem.MobilePhone = newMobilePhoneNumber;
  var errorCode = ohem.Update();
  // Deal with error, if any
}
```

If you hire a *new* salesperson, you would add the EmployeesInfo first and note the new person's EmployeeId; then add the Salespersons record and fill in the EmployeeId.